# getexternalstoragedirectory does not exist

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files, android-external-storage

I'm trying to build an app that uses expansion files. From the Android documentation, it seems `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory` is the right method for accessing the location of these files. However, when I debug my app, this returns `/storage/emulated/0` which fails the `File.exists()` check and the app cannot find this directory. I've read through many posts but am still  thoroughly confused with what's happening.

Some suggest that this is a virtual directory which maps to the physical path `/mnt/shell/emulated/0` which **does exist** when I view in File Manager.

Others suggest that read/write access is needed in the manifest.xml but I also tried adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` with no luck.

What is going on? I'm using Android Studio with GenyMotion to debug my app. The virtual device is Sony Xperia Z - 4.3 - API 18.

Comment: The framework may very well fail an exists check due to the symbolic link, but what does "the app cannot find this directory" mean? Do you get an error trying to read or write certain files?

Comment: I just meant the same thing that the exists fails. How can I get the location of my expansion files then?

Comment: I had a similar problem which was caused by not actually giving the permission to the app to access External Storage (depending on how app was installed). Try checking in Settings->Apps->[YourApp]->Permissions. Hope that helps.